# What's the difference between trigger('click') and click() on jQuery

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm looking for the difference in performance between those two, I could not found in SSE no good answer about this topic.

Some examples would be of great help.

Comment: There isn't any. One calls the other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the jQuery code you can see that all `click()` does is execute `trigger('click')`:

```
jQuery.each( ("blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick " +
"mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave " +
"change select submit keydown keypress keyup error contextmenu").split(" "), function( i, name ) {

// Handle event binding
jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( data, fn ) {
    if ( fn == null ) {
        fn = data;
        data = null;
    }

    return arguments.length > 0 ?
        this.on( name, null, data, fn ) :
        this.trigger( name );
};
```

Note this:

```
    return arguments.length > 0 ?
        this.on( name, null, data, fn ) :
        this.trigger( name );
```

In other words, "If no arguments are passed to `click`, execute `trigger('click')`".

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that this is Standard Operating Procedure in the jQuery source code, or in any decent application for that matter -- if you want the same result, call the same code. The difference in performance between one and the other will always be negligible.