# event different in "click with mouse" and "trigger"

Tags: javascript

I have a bind event like:

```
$(document).on('click', selector, proxy);
```

what is the difference between **"click with mouse"** and "`do a trigger` `XXX.trigger('click');`"
what is their principle in calling callback function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between .click() and actually clicking a button? (javascript/jquery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127908/difference-between-click-and-actually-clicking-a-button-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Both are almost same, but `click()` is shorthand of `trigger('click')`.

More info [here](http://jsperf.com/trigger-vs-not-trigger).

I found this info too, in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10230050/2841382).

Comment: thanks, but what i asked is "live mouse click" and "trigger('click')". i think it is different between these two ways. or you think a mouse click is same as call the click() function?

Comment: I think so. To make 'click' you must do it with mouse. With trigger is the same (in my second ref. is explined), but you could "schedule" an event to make click too.